# Postgresql Create Table Fieldname Timestamp with Time Zone UTC

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, create-table

What is the syntax for creating a table with a field with the UTC time zone?

I have for the fields:

```
(id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
 bravo timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
 charlie timestamp with time zone UTC DEFAULT now()
)
```

This last field named `charlie` is not taking for some reason.  I was hoping it was easy as just telling it had a time zone, then shoving UTC in there, and having the db figure out `now()` during input.

Comment: `charlie is not taking`  what that mean? show sample data, what/how are you inserting, what are you getting. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm tired.  the charlie field is throwing the error, at "UTC...".  There is no data.  I'm trying to create a table using `CREATE TABLE mytable ...` using what I already posted.  I have read those.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
charlie timestamp without time zone NOT NULL
   DEFAULT (current_timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
```

Comment: I do want to set this field with a timezone for reporting later on.  I see how you have changed the approach to `now()`.  Will give it a try.

Comment: You cannot store time zones with timestamps in PostgreSQL. The type `timestamp with time zone` is actually an UTC timestamp that is converted to your client's time zone upon retrieval. What I suggested will always return the same constant time zone that is the value as it was in UTC when the row was inserted.

Comment: OK that seems like it would fit the job.  Thx.

Comment: I ended up doing `charlie timestamptz not null default NOW()`